# CodeIgniter Call to undefined function odbc_connect

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, windows-server-2016

I am running Codeigniter 1.7 on Xampp 3.2 and on the index page I have:

```
Call to undefined function odbc_connect
```

Pdo is enabled (php.info):

```
ODBC Connection Pooling Enabled, strict matching
```

I have then installed odbc drivers and enabled in php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

not sure about this last step, I have also same name modules but called 'nts'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, missing in php.ini:

```
extension=php_odbc.dll
```